# categories and sub-categories sql order sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, categories

I have the following tables

table_name: categories

```
id   name        parent  
16   Rash Vest   41  
17   Shorts      41  
20   Tops        41  
41   Shop        0  
47   Mens        16  
48   Womens      16
```

table_name: items

```
id   title                 alias                 catid  
70   Rash Vest Black       rash-vest-black       47   
96   Rash Vest Red         rash-vest-red         47  
98   Rash Vest Womens Red  rash-vest-womens-red  48
```

Now I want to display all items according to the root tree..

Like This
Main Menu: **SHOP**
Sub Menus: **Rash Vest** | Shorts |  Tops
Child categories:
Mens
----->Rash Vest Black
----->Rash Vest Red
Womens
----->Rash Vest Womens Red

Comment: Your question is labelled both mysql and sql-server.  What database are you really using?

Comment: sorry.. I'm using mysql

Comment: . . That is a shame, because SQL Server supports recursive queries and this is very hard in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL-SERVER versio**:

```
;WITH groups AS
(SELECT ID
 , Name
 , ParentID
 , 0 AS Level
 , CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
 FROM Category WHERE ParentID = 0

 UNION ALL

 SELECT c.ID
 , c.Name
 , c.ParentID
 , g.Level + 1
 , CAST(CAST(g.Path AS VARCHAR(255)) + 
        CAST(' -> ' AS VARCHAR(255)) + 
        CAST(c.Name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
 FROM Category c 
 INNER JOIN groups g ON g.ID = c.ParentID
)

SELECT g.Name
, g.Level
, g.Path
, ISNULL(itm.Title, 'No items') AS Title
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN Item itm ON itm.CategoryID = g.ID
ORDER BY g.Path
```

If you want show result as in question, than this part of work for User-interface(your application)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4f99/17) for example/testing